# Connect to ASE sybase in Robotframework using databaseLibrary

Tags: robotframework, sybase

I'm trying to connect to Sysbase but i have always the error

Suite setup failed:

> OperationalError: ('08001', u"[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]Ce serveur SQL n'existe pas ou son acc\xe8s est
>   refus\xe9. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)")

My code is:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup       Connect To Database    pyodbc    ${DBName}    ${DBUser}    
${DBPass}    ${DBHost}    ${DBPort}
Suite Teardown    Disconnect From Database
Library           Selenium2Library
Resource          ../../../Keywords/Initialisation/Initialisation.robot
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${DBHost}         ""
${DBName}         ""
${DBPass}         ""
${DBPort}         ""
${DBUser}         ""

*** Test Cases ***
Récupérer CAB
${output} =    Execute SQL String    select "" from "" where ""= '80000204000048' ;
Log    ${output}
```

I have installed databaselibrary 
    pip install robotframework-databaselibrary and pyodbc 
    ">pip install pyodbc"

Comment: Do you have a complete minimal example that includes the connection as well. Right now this information is missing.

Comment: this examplr is complete the connection is in Suite setup " Connect To Database    pyodbc    ${DBName}    ${DBUser}    
${DBPass}    ${DBHost}    ${DBPort}"

Comment: You're using a MS SQL Server ODBC driver based upon your error message -  this will not work for Sybase ASE which requires a SAP Adaptive Enterprise Server ODBC driver instead.